# Find files modified between 2 dates from Source directory(Recursively) and copy it into the Target directory with same directory structure

Tags: files, directory, copy, directory-structure, ksh

I am trying to copy the files from source to Target folder which has been modified between 2 dates,

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

source=/home/Amal/DELTA/SOURCE

target=/home/Amal/DELTA/TARGET

cd $source

find ./ -type f -newermt "2021-07-08 00:00:00" ! -newermt "2021-09-18 23:59:55" -printf "%h:%p:\0" |

while IFS=":" read path file; do

cp "$file" "$target"/"$path"

done
```

NOTE: Source and directory is having same directory structure already. I just need to copy the files as same as SOURCE directory.

When i execute this script no changes in TARGET folder.

Comment: You are piping null-delimited data into the loop, but afaik ksh's `read` expects newline-delimited data by default

Comment: @Steeldriver - Even after removing the \0 from the find command no changes. The files are not copied to TARGET.

Comment: @Amala you would need to **replace** `\0` with `\n` in the `printf` - or switch to bash where `read -d ''` can be used to read null-delimited "lines"

Comment: @steeldriver - Thank you so much. Replacing \0 with \n worked.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use `rsync` with the `--include-from-file` option. `rsync` is a versatile file copy utility that will by default copy directory structures. With the `--include-from-file` option, you can point `rsync` to a list, a text file, that determines the files that should be included in the copy. Such list can be created with the `find` command.

So first run the `find` to locate the desired files and list them in a text file. Then use `rsync` to only copy these files over. Easy to script once you got it working, obviously.

Comment: rsync is not available in our application server(Linux Server).

Comment: That is quite important information that you may want to add to your question. Use "edit". I will leave the answer up because a vast majority of users will be able to install and use rsync.